# Error trying to deserialize RestSharp response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, restsharp

I ran into an error in this piece of code

```
 public PaymentResponse CreatePaymentRequest(string amount, string mobile, string email, string description,
         long orderId)
    {
        amount = amount.Replace(",", "");
        var finalAmount = int.Parse(amount);
        var siteUrl = _configuration.GetSection("payment")["siteUrl"];

        var client = new RestClient($"https://{Prefix}.zarinpal.com/pg/rest/WebGate/PaymentRequest.json");
        var request = new RestRequest(siteUrl,Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var body = new PaymentRequest
        {
            Mobile = mobile,
            CallbackURL = $"{siteUrl}/Checkout?handler=CallBack&oId={orderId}",
            Description = description,
            Email = email,
            Amount = finalAmount,
            MerchantID = MerchantId
        };
        request.AddJsonBody(body);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        return jsonSerializer.Deserialize<PaymentResponse>(response);
    }
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'RestSharp.RestResponse' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader'

[image: Image of codes]

I even used content but it didn't work

```
return jsonSerializer.Deserialize<PaymentResponse>(response.Content);
```

or

```
 var response = client.Execute(request).Content;
        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        return jsonSerializer.Deserialize<PaymentResponse>(response);
```

Imported namespaces:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
```

Comment: _"but it didn't work"_ -  how EXACTLY it did not work? Class was not deserialized correctly? If yes - post the json. It has thrown an exception - please post it, and the json.

Comment: The result of [RestClient.Execute](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/6197f314dca6e77d22f233ec976dea812a73eac0/src/RestSharp/RestClient.Extensions.cs#L50) is a `RestResponse<T>` not a string. It already contains the deserialized object in its [Data](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/Response/RestResponse.cs#L33) property

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the response is only deserialised when one uses `Execute<T>`

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev and I link to that method's source

Answer (score 2):

`RestSharp` comes with build-in possibility to deserialize responses, it also [supports Newtonsoft's Json.NET](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net), if you want to use it (though personally I would not), so try something like the following (`RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson` package is needed):

```cs
RestClient client = new RestClient("...", configureSerialization: config => config.UseNewtonsoftJson());

var resp = await client.ExecuteAsync<PaymentResponse>();

return resp.Data;
```